# How to achieve a horizontal borders in css with text vertical centered

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Border Image]

I have tried some different tricks for this border like border left, but it appear on the whole line and i need a "or" between this, i can easily do this in horizontal order but i am stuck in vertical, can someone please help me out in this.

`In case if someone wants the source code` - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mezubeen/e36hzyes/)

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use dev tools and see how the they styled it ?

Comment: i have just a image,not a web page

Comment: this seem like stackoverflow signup page :)

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you want the social register button is inline with your form horizontally? Because in your image, the Form and social button is inline horizontally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have separated them in two vertical lines, which makes it more controllable for a Developer.

```css
p {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<hr width="1" size="100">
<p>or</p>
<hr width="1" size="100">
```

Use something like media query to hide the lines when the screen size is smaller than X.